# I am trying to read a log file. It opens using notepad as txt file. However when I try using python to read the file it doesn't open

Tags: python, file-io, logfile

This is the error I get when I try reading in the file.

```
 logfile = open(r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/access.txt')

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/access.txt'


logfile = open(r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/access.log')



with open(logfile, 'r') as read:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

As you can see, when I try to read as a txt file it doesn't recognize the file. When I try to read as a log file it finds the file but generates an error.

Any suggestions on how to read this file in. It's a simple text file with rows like this

[02/Jan/2015:08:07:32] "GET /click?article_id=162&user_id=5475 HTTP/1.1" 200 4352

I've already tried changing the name of file to txt and that doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing the first line to `logfile = 'C:/Users...access.log'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error one: the File
`r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/access.txt'`
does not exist.
Error two:
The file
`'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/access.log'`
does exist but the function `open(...)` expects a string that is the full path to the file. In the line `with open(logfile, 'r') as read:` the variable `logfile` is already a file-object, not a string anymore.
Try the following:

```
logFilePath = r'C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/data_scientist_test/access_log/access.log'
with open(logFilePath, 'r') as fileObject:
    pass # do the stuff you want with the file
    # When you leave this indentation, the file object will be closed again
```